# Optimizing for speed. Moving skewness finder. Cumulative sum proving to be bottleneck

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, cumulative-sum

Helllo,
I have written the below provided function to calculate the moving window skewness of a time series.
To find out where the bottleneck is I used tic/toc and it seems the part where the cumulative sum (T2) is calculated takes the most amount of time.
The fraction of time taken (for each section) depends on N, the size of the time series. For N = 1000000 the cumsum takes around 83% of the time.

**The Concern:**
How can I speed up this code? Or has it reached its limit?

```
function sk_timeseries = moving_skewness(x, window_size, window_step)
    
    % T1 start
    X1 = x;
    X2 = X1 .* x;
    X3 = X2 .* x;
    % T1 end
    
    % T2 start
    S1 = cumsum([0, X1]);
    S2 = cumsum([0, X2]);
    S3 = cumsum([0, X3]);
    % T2 end
    
    % T3 start
    % Get the indices at which to calculate skewness values
    window_ends_idx = window_size: window_step: length(x);
    
    % Preallocate array for storing skewness time series
    sk_timeseries = zeros(1, length(window_ends_idx));
    
    N = window_size;
    % T3 end
    
    % T4 start
    % Generate skewness time series
    for k = 1: length(window_ends_idx)
        j = window_ends_idx(k) + 1;
        i = j - window_size;
        
        % Calculate M1_ji
        M1_ji = (S1(j) - S1(i)) / N;
        
        % Calculate necessary central moments
        M2_ji = (S2(j) - S2(i)) - window_size * M1_ji * M1_ji;
        M3_ji = (S3(j) - S3(i)) - 3 * M1_ji * (S2(j) - S2(i)) + 2 * N * M1_ji * M1_ji * M1_ji;

        % Calculate skewness
        sk_timeseries(k) = sqrt(N) * M3_ji / (M2_ji^1.5);
    end
    % T4 end

end
```

Comment: `cumsum` can't be parallelized, like other operations are. But do [use the profiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) to figure out what bits take most time. `tic`/`toc` is not reliable for very short times.

Comment: `[0, X1]` makes a copy, it could also be taking up time. It would be cheaper to start with `x = [0,x]`, before computing `X1` etc. Then you don't need to pad three times, just one time.

Comment: I tried moving the padding out like I suggested above, but I still see `cumsum` being the hottest lines. They went down from 18-20% of the time each to 13-14%. It's worth making the change, but it's not a significant gain. I think you are at the limit.